# Code efficiency and speed comparison in javascript -assignment vs conditional checking

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a timer object written in javascript and my goal is to make it as efficient and fast and thus as accurate as possible.

One of my concerns has to do with a specific case that could generally be applied to all manners of coding and I'm sure has been asked before, I just am not sure what terms to use when searching for it.

My question is which of these 2 cases is faster/more efficient?

Case 1: Assigning a variable some value in a repeated section of code, even when you know the value only needs to be assigned once.

Case 2: Checking the value of the variable, thus conditionally assigning it.

```
function runOnce(){
    timer.someValue = { //some object...};
}


function someRepeatedFunction(){
    timer.someValue = null;

    //vs

    if(timer.someValue){
        timer.someValue = null;
    }
}
```

Which of those cases would be faster?

Comment: This is micro-optimisation. The difference is negligible. You will waste more time in determining the answer to this than you will ever recover in improved performance.

Comment: Okay I can understand that. In that case I would choose the option with fewer lines of code.  Still though for curiosity sake, if a clear answer does exist from a theory side, I wouldn't mind knowing it. Of course I am coding a timer so I know I could just setup a test case and actually...time it.

Comment: @krb686: That's what you should do.

Comment: I am currently in the process of doing so.  Even still, I see no reason for the down vote.  Not knowing an answer is not a good reason, and this is a legitimate question and curiosity of mine. Even if 99.9% of the code anyone ever writes doesn't need such accuracy, what harm is there in trying to be more accurate and efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Micro-optimization #1

If you insist on the conditional checking, I would bypass using the `==` operator (that I think Javascript uses automatically) and go for the `===` operator.

The identity `===` operator behaves identically to the equality `==` operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal.The `==` operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary type conversions. The `===` operator will not do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type `===` will simply return false. It's this case where `===` will be faster, and may return a different result than `==`. In all other cases performance will be the same.

Micro-optimization #2

With respect to the choice between the assignment & conditional checking, it seems logical to go for assignment in the case of using a global variable (like the one you seem to be using). Unless you plan on handling cases in an `else` situation there's no need to continually check what the current typeof the object or it's value is.